# Programmatically disable "Shake to find pointer" MacOS feature without hiding cursor

Tags: macos, mouseevent, cgeventtap

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302581/programatically-disable-shake-to-find), but that's different to what I am looking for, as the accepted answer hides the cursor.

I'm writing software that remaps the left mouse button to the left CTRL key.

I have it working, with one problem: when I hold down the CTRL key and drag the mouse pointer this feature often activates, which messes up my drag operation (it feels like trying to change direction running on ice).

So the Apple engineers must have disabled this feature while the left mouse button is down and re-enabled it when the button is released.

Something like this -- however when I inject my simulated mouse events, the feature does not disable.

What I'm getting at is: there must be some programmatic way of doing it, even if it is an internal Apple function. Unless Apple are using the solution in the linked answer, i.e. `NSCursor.hide()` and then manually drawing the cursor icon at the cursor location.

How can I accomplish this cleanly?

EDIT: A `CGEventTap` for `NSEventTypeGesture` or `NSEventTypeMagnify` fails to catch anything.